# How refresh title highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to refresh of the value of my pie chart when I press some field of the legend.

For example: I have 471 request and when I press in field "App Android" in the legend, I will have 426 and I want to take this value and refresh the title. My code: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2133/

```
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    layout: 'vertical',
    x: 0,
    y: 100,
    labelFormatter: function () {
        $scope.data = this.total;
        console.log($scope.data);
        return this.y + ' ('+ this.percentage.toFixed(2) +'%) - ' +this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `plotOptions.series.point.events.legendItemClick` to update the title when the item is clicked. This isn't fitted for pie charts, but it can be used. See this example:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                    var newTotal = this.total + (event.target.visible ? -event.target.y : event.target.y);
                    this.series.chart.setTitle({ text: 'Chart title ' + newTotal});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It first calculates the new total, since the event is fired before the point is removed, this has to take that into account manually. After that it uses the `Chart.setTitle` function to update the title.

See [this updated JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2134/) of how it works.